# Google SignIn SDK pass openIDRealm to get openID

Tags: ios, openid, google-signin

I have an existing website which is using google openID format start with "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id".
I am creating an IOS app using Google plus SignIn and want to get this openID so user data can be consistent on IOS and existing WebSite using the same database.

I followed Google SDK tutorial and tried to pass in openIDRealm parameter, but got error message: openIDRealm parameter is not allowed for this type of message.

I googled for quite some times but I couldn't find a way to pass openIDRealm successfully and get openID. How do I get openID from IOS device?

Or maybe I am doing things entirely wrong, what should I do for users to login on IOS using openID?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered linking users via email addresses instead of emails to find users in your database (only for the iOS case)?  This solution is not ideal as email addresses are not stable identifiers but it should work with the vast majority of the cases and you could add a fail-over mechanism for edge cases that break.

Hope that helps!